# Bind a datatrigger to a property of a data object

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an ItemsControl where I would like to bind set the data template according to a property in my data object. My default template contains a textbox for a numerical value, which I would like to replace with a checkbox when my object contains a value which can only be 0 or 1. The datatrigger should bind to IsBoolean, which is a property of one of the workflow parameters in the ItemsSource. I think that what I have right now trys to bind to an IsBoolean property in my DataContext. What is the correct way to specify the source?

Here is the XAML:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WorkflowParameters}" IsTabStop="False">                
            <ItemsControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5">
                                        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                            <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                            </ToolTip>
                                        </TextBlock.ToolTip>                                
                                    </TextBlock>

                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding DefaultValue, StringFormat=N3}" Margin="5" Width="100"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Unit}" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBoolean}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5">
                                                <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                                    <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                                    </ToolTip>
                                                </TextBlock.ToolTip>                                
                                            </TextBlock>

                                            <CheckBox Command="{Binding SetBooleanValue}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                        </Grid>                                            
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.Style>

        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I decided to go with the DataTemplateSelector, which I got working readily. I still would like to know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say for sure. But based on what you posted, it looks like you are trying to use the `ItemsControl` style to set the template, which would a) set the template for _all_ items in the collection, and b) refer to the `ItemsControl` data context, not each individual item. More likely what you should be doing is using a single template that itself shows/hides appropriate members depending on the `IsBoolean` value.